# Create Dynamic Html.ActionLink

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-2, view, controller, html.actionlink

I would like to generate a dynamic Html.Action link after a button click from a View.  Currently I am using ajax to update a

tag on the form with a randomly generated product name from a DB.  My code looks like this:

```
<p>
   <%using (Ajax.BeginForm("RandomProductName", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "result" }))
    { %>           
        <input type="submit" value="Generate Random Product"/>

 <% } %>
</p>
<p id="result"></p>
```

The "RandomProductName" method in the controller returns a string value of the type of product.  I would like to be able to turn this into a dynamic Html.Action link similar to <%=Html.ActionLink("Pliers", "Details", new {id = "2"})%> to display the detail view.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated as I am just learning the framework this weekend.

Updated: Here is the code for my current method:

```
public PartialViewResult RandomProductLink()
    {
        int id = RandomProductID();
        Product product = GetProduct(id);

        return PartialView(Product.Name);
        //i think i need to return something like - <%= Html.ActionLink(Product.Name, "Details" new {id=Product.ID})%>
    }
```

Comment: edited so code block displays.  sorry this was not shown at first.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**
Now that I can see your code, it seems pretty straight forward. The simplest way would be to change your RandomProductName action to return a PartialViewResult that would return the contents of a user control.

```
public PartialViewResult RandomProductName()
{
    ProductNameModel productName = GenerateRandomProductName();
    return PartialView(productName);
}
```

Your model might look like this

```
public class ProductNameModel
{
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

Your user control might look like this

```
<%= Html.ActionLink(Model.Name, "Details", new { id = Model.Id }) %>
```

Comment: Yads - thanks for your help.  Could you please give me an example of how I would update the action link parameters through the "RandoProductName"?  Lets say for example that the method gets the name and the detail id.  How would I update the Model?    Ex. <%=Html.ActionLink("Hammer", "Details", new {id = "5"})%>

Comment: @Yads - I have been looking at this too long and my brain is mush.  Currently the RandomProductName method updates the "results" paragraph tag once the button is clicked.  Would the ActionLink be built in the RandoProductName method and get passed?  I only want the ActionLink to show when the button is clicked.

Comment: @baileybelle, the RandomProductName method would return html containing the contents of the user control. Once evaluated would be an `<a>` tag with the appropriate url. This HTML would be inserted into the `<p>` tag.

Comment: @Yads, thats what i thought.  although i cannot seem to format the Html.Actionlink properly in the return.  I updated my orginal code with the current RandomProductLink method.  could you please provide an example with the correct format?  Thanks so much.

Comment: @baileybelle, without seeing your RandomeProductName control, it's a little tough to tell, but you need to pass in a complex model that contains both the name and the id. Rather than just the name. Read my answer again carefully.